# Visual C++ 9 Linker file size limitation

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

It appears that the visual C++ 9 linker has a file allocation algorithm that doubles the size of the file every allocation, so you get 512mb, 1024mb, 2048mb, 4096mb. The problem is that it is using a library that cannot handle files larger 2048MB, and as such crashes with an error such as "cannot read file at  is the disk full or write protected".

Is there a way to bypass this limitation or otherwise replace the linker with something else that works?

A bit of background, I have a code generator that generates a large number of files, ~15k cpp files, I've managed to reduce the number of files to something about 6k to get something that at least completes the linking process, I would like to be able to include all 15k without having to create multiple libs.

Comment: mmm, maybe split your code into multiple DLLs

Comment: The code is a static lib, so the compiled code is much much smaller, IE, the debug version of the dll i compiled which used some code from this static lib is 5MB (which is still large)

Comment: A hard crash at 2 gigs suggests that the linker users 32 bit signed integers to adress the content of the file. That will be hard to work around.